# Flash: importing swf having filters

Tags: flash, animation, filter

I've made a Flash animation which includes filters. When I import that swf into another flash file, it ignores the filters. When importing swf it converts animation into keyframes . Surely there's no GPU rendering issue here. Whats going wrong ?